# Trouble with Web.Config Transform

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-config, web-config-transform

I have a multiple projects with the same issue and I have even started an empty web project and have the same issues. I am using VS Professional 2015 update 3.

I can use Configuration Manager to create new configurations but I can not get them to be applied to my Web Site project. It will apply to the class project but not the web project. I have created a solution with an empty web project and had the same experience.

Since I can not get the configs applying the publish transforms are not working which is why I am trying to make these changes.

I have created Configs for release and staging and the project will perform the transform but will only transform the debug config file no matter what the publish profile has.

I can create the new configuration

[Creating the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPwTh.png)

Sometimes the create new project configuration checkbox is not enabled.

After this I go to the web project and I try to change the config and the option is not there. (I can not post more than one image)

I closed Visual Studio and reopened and the new config is there but still not available to the web project.

I have reviewed the SLN file and the configurations are there:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Staging|Any CPU = Staging|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
```

The projects have all the platforms

```
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {38C7D9CE-2252-409A-8FD3-D1D520DE48EC}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {38C7D9CE-2252-409A-8FD3-D1D520DE48EC}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {38C7D9CE-2252-409A-8FD3-D1D520DE48EC}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {38C7D9CE-2252-409A-8FD3-D1D520DE48EC}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {38C7D9CE-2252-409A-8FD3-D1D520DE48EC}.Staging|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Staging|Any CPU
        {38C7D9CE-2252-409A-8FD3-D1D520DE48EC}.Staging|Any CPU.Build.0 = Staging|Any CPU
        {76F1526B-B354-4531-9C00-3E963EB6DDE6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {76F1526B-B354-4531-9C00-3E963EB6DDE6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {76F1526B-B354-4531-9C00-3E963EB6DDE6}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {76F1526B-B354-4531-9C00-3E963EB6DDE6}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {76F1526B-B354-4531-9C00-3E963EB6DDE6}.Staging|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {76F1526B-B354-4531-9C00-3E963EB6DDE6}.Staging|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
```

I have verified that the show advanced configurations box is checked.

I am at a loss as to why this is not working and I have been beating on it for a few days but can not find anything promising.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The project was set up as a website and not a web application this was causing the transform issues. Converting the project to an application solved the issue.